# Highlighting text in a new window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a recipe page where a user can click a recipe ingredient (e.g. olive oil, broccoli, etc.) and get redirected to list of ingredients with the ingredient they clicked highlighted in yellow.

I know how to highlight text with a specific link:

CSS:

```
.highlight {background-Color:yellow;}
```

Javascript:

```
function highlightText(id) 
{
    var textObject = document.getElementById(id);

    textObject.className = "highlight";
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1 id="ingredient">Olive Oil</h1>
<a href="javascript:highlightText('ingredient')">Olive Oil</a>
```

What I would like to do is create a link to "Olive Oil" from another page, the way you would using the id attribute:

```
<a href="http://www.mypage.com/recipe-list.html#ingredient">
    Olive Oil
</a>
```

I appreciate any and all help. This is my first post, so please excuse me for asking such a simple question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the target selector

```
:target{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

[An article about that selector](http://css-tricks.com/on-target/)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was actually on this this site earlier but must have missed this section :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to highlight images, texts, or html documents, you can use lightbox.

Just try it: http://jquery-jkit.com/commands/lightbox.html